# Specific table view on mobile only with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a table layout, and it looks good on desktop (769px+).

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th colspan="2">Product</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>31.23 USD</td>
        <td>2 pcs</td>
        <td>62.46 USD</td>
        <td><a href="#">x</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>31.23 USD</td>
        <td>2 pcs</td>
        <td>62.46 USD</td>
        <td><a href="#">x</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td>31.23 USD</td>
        <td>2 pcs</td>
        <td>62.46 USD</td>
        <td><a href="#">x</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I want this a little bit different on my mobile (and tablet) (768px-).

**Here is a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/etd89po5/**

[image: the normal view]

[image: mobile view]

You can see: the current table is on the upper picture, and I want the same appearance as the table below, but I dont want to duplicate the HTML code (for example: make two tables, and hide one with media query), I want to do this with CSS only.

If it is necessary, I can change the table elements to divs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use @media width.  here is link http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Yes, I am using media queries, but the question was focused on breaking rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it as a `<table>` for accessibility definitely. In your media query for smaller sizes, you could do something like:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    tr { display: block; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 1em; text-align: center; }
    td { display: inline; padding: 0 .5em; }
}
```

That wouldn’t force a line break though. The easiest way to get around that would be to add a `<br>` element to your second cell and hide it in your desktop CSS:

```
td>br { display: none; }
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    td>br { display: block; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you do this?

```
<div>Full table:</div>
 <table id="desktop">
  <thead>....

 <table id="mobile">
  <thead>....

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px){
 #desktop{
  display:block;
 }
 #mobile{
  display:none;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px){
 #desktop{
  display:none;
 }
 #mobile{
  display:block;
 }
}
```

Comment: As I said, I dont want to duplicate the tables, so thanks, but it's not an option.